# Laravel 5 'a' character printed out

Tags: laravel-5

I have this issue where there's an 'a' character printed out on all the pages above everything else, it seems that it appears before the DOCTYPE, I can't find it anywhere!

master.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>@yield('title')</title>
   @include('elements.css')
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
 @include('elements.html.navbartop')
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 80px;margin-bottom: 40px">
    @yield('content')
  </div>
 </div>
@include('elements.html.footer')
@include('elements.js')
```

index.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout.master')

@section('title', 'Home Index')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        @include('elements.session.flash')
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 style="margin-bottom: 30px">Home Index</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Post the code of one page

Comment: Can you share your `layout` page?

Comment: If it appears only in a certain set of pages, I would suspect it's a specific controller/view. Otherwise, it could be in your routes, it could be in your main layers view, it could be in a middleware. It could be a lot of things really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind I found it at the beginning of filesystems.php accidental typo made by who knows who or what.

```
a<?php
```

sorry